# Running Websockets with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, flask-socketio

I have a flask app that runs both flask and flask-socketio endpoints. When i went to deploy on google App engine, i realized that websockets are not supported by app engine. this means that i need to use compute engine for my flask-socketio and app engine for my regular flask endpoints i assume. how would i go about creating these two instances and run them in parallel while being connected to one another? is this possible? if im not on the right track with my train of thought please point me in the right direction.

Comment: One option may be to use [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) - which supports WebSockets and much of the App Engine auto-scaling and deployment functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can run how many instance you want running in parallel to scale our service in your case you may think about creating a cluster.
You can Use Compute Engine for WebSocket Server, Google decided to combine App Engine with Compute Engine to implement the connection with WebSocket servers.
Here a Google public document that explain [WebSocket on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket#using_compute_engine_for_websocket_server)